Spring boot azure function : This function was programmatically called via the host APIs
I am trying to create a spring boot azure function using the following guide
https://github.com/eggboy/springcloud-azurefunction/tree/springboot3
https://medium.com/microsoftazure/create-azure-function-with-spring-cloud-function-ab150216d2bd
I was able to successfully build and run the azure function on local.
but when I try to deploy and trigger the http endpoint, I am getting following error with 500 error.
Could someone help understand what is going wrong here.
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=57887aec-5989-45c1-bb34-453059bc2c5b)
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '57887aec-5989-45c1-bb34-453059bc2c5b
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:57887aec-5989-45c1-bb34-453059bc2c5b on workerId:18a329dc-7f2e-4e0b-8487-c67d912b9eea
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Failed, Id=57887aec-5989-45c1-bb34-453059bc2c5b, Duration=5ms)
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Checking worker statuses (Count=1)
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Worker status: ID=18a329dc-7f2e-4e0b-8487-c67d912b9eea, Latency=1ms
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 68): History=(0,0,0,0,1), AvgCpuLoad=0.2, MaxCpuLoad=1
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host process CPU stats (PID 26): History=(2,3,2,2,3), AvgCpuLoad=2, MaxCpuLoad=3
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Verbose]   [HostMonitor] Host aggregate CPU load 3
2024-06-15T04:10:37Z   [Information]   Executing StatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200
2024-06-15T04:10:39Z   [Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name 'getUserFunction' and template 'api/getUserFunction'
2024-06-15T04:10:39Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8d7fe07c-108e-4f3b-886e-8a95750737b8)
2024-06-15T04:10:39Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '8d7fe07c-108e-4f3b-886e-8a95750737b8
2024-06-15T04:10:39Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:8d7fe07c-108e-4f3b-886e-8a95750737b8 on workerId:18a329dc-7f2e-4e0b-8487-c67d912b9eea
2024-06-15T04:10:39Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Failed, Id=8d7fe07c-108e-4f3b-886e-8a95750737b8, Duration=5ms)
2024-06-15T04:10:41Z   [Verbose]   Request successfully matched the route with name 'getUserFunction' and template 'api/getUserFunction'
2024-06-15T04:10:41Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7fba93bb-0744-4af3-8bb3-a604b8a5c4bd)
2024-06-15T04:10:41Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '7fba93bb-0744-4af3-8bb3-a604b8a5c4bd
2024-06-15T04:10:41Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:7fba93bb-0744-4af3-8bb3-a604b8a5c4bd on workerId:18a329dc-7f2e-4e0b-8487-c67d912b9eea
2024-06-15T04:10:41Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.getUserFunction' (Failed, Id=7fba93bb-0744-4af3-8bb3-a604b8a5c4bd, Duration=7ms)

https://xxx/api/getUserFunction?userId=abc
Error seen from browser
I am expecting successful return HTTP 200 response by the azure http trigger via both browser and postman, but both fails to with 500 error. But on local it works and return the expected result with HTTP 200
My trigger code is here
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import io.jaylee.springcloud.model.UserDTO;
import io.jaylee.springcloud.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FunctionHandler {

    private final UserService userService;

    @FunctionName("createUserFunction")
    public HttpResponseMessage createUser(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<UserDTO>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        if (request == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request cannot be null");
        }

        context.getLogger()
               .info(request.getBody()
                             .map(UserDTO::toString).orElse(""));
        userService.saveUser(request.getBody().orElseThrow());

        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }

    @FunctionName("getUserFunction")
    public HttpResponseMessage getUser(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        String userId = request.getQueryParameters().get("userId");

        if (userId == null || "".equals(userId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request cannot be null");
        }

        context.getLogger().info(userId);
        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(userService.getUser(userId))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }
}

local.setting.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  }
}

host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

UserService.java
import io.jaylee.springcloud.model.User;
import io.jaylee.springcloud.model.UserDTO;
import io.jaylee.springcloud.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Component
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public String saveUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        var user = User.builder()
                       .userId(userDTO.getUserId())
                       .lastName(userDTO.getLastName())
                       .firstName(userDTO.getFirstName())
                       .email(userDTO.getEmail())
                       .createdOn(ZonedDateTime.now())
                       .build();

        return userRepository.save(user).getUserId();
    }

    public UserDTO getUser(String userId) {
        var user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(new User());

        return new UserDTO(user.getUserId(),
                           user.getLastName(), user.getFirstName(), user.getEmail());
    }
}


The log you included has a 200 success code. Have you included the right part? What are you using to trigger the function? Browser? Fiddler/Postman?

I tried using both Brower and Postman, but both returned a 500 error.

Have you set your Azure function resource's runtime to Java? If so, check runtime version on local vs cloud. It may help if you include some code, too. Where is the user abc being looked up from local vs remote?

@RoshanBogahapitiya The function is getting executed properly and giving 200 success code. but the code inside the trigger is giving error. share your trigger code.

@ArchitectJamie, I have runtime stack set to java , Runtime Stack
Java 17 SE on both local and azure cloud.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya, I have updated my question with trigger code

@ArchitectJamie, user abc being looked from h2 in memory db

@RoshanBogahapitiya, please share your GitHub repo if possible.

@RoshanBogahapitiya, please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Have a look at this https://github.com/egch/springboot-azure-Integration, It's a simplified,  fully working, version of that one referred by you (eggboy)

Check the invocation logs of your Azure function for the details about the cause of the error when you get 500 status code.


You can follow MSDOC to create a Spring-Boot Azure function.

I have created a Spring Boot Azure function and deployed to Azure.


Deployed the function to Azure function App.




Thanks @Pravallika KV for the answer, I decided to go with normal java azure function instead of spring boot as it was taking time for investigation.
